# How to translate "hall of fame" into Latin?

Tags: word-choice

What would be the idiomatic way to say "hall of fame" (a structure housing memorials to famous or illustrious individuals) in Latin?

I feel like "templum/aedes gloariae/famae/honoris" would be equally good. I don't know enough about the nuances between these terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Romans made wax masks called *imagines* of their illustrious family members. Typically, when someone attained a senatorial rank (*aedilis* or above), they would press their face into wax, which would make a mask. Illustrious clans would show off these masks in their *atrium*. This is probably the closest thing we have to an actual "hall" of fame.

To describe these family members, you have a variety of words at your disposal. Very often they would be *clari* or *nobilissimi*, and both words are suitable for this sort of thing.

I suppose one can argue that [Cornelius Nepos' *De Viris Inlustribus*](https://ephor.us/epitome/cornelius-nepos/) functions a bit like a "hall of fame" for famous people. It is made up of a series of biographies divided up by profession. Sadly, most of it is gone. [Suetonius](https://ephor.us/epitome/suetonius/) and later Jerome uses the title (using the assimilated *ill-* for *inl-*) for their versions of the project, so the word is attractive for this purpose.

Putting this all together and choosing this last word, you get:

> Atrium Illustrium ("Atrium of the Illustrious Ones")

I removed the *Viris* to keep it gender neutral, but if this hall of fame is for some group in particular, you can add that to it.